# sharepoint designer Workflow to start when an item value is changed error

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

I have 2 Sharepoint designer list workflow for one list. The first workflow will start when an item is created and the second workflow starts when an item is changed. When the first workflow finish i set a value for the column "sofortige Implementierung" and second workflow should start when the value is "sofortige Implementierung". 
The second is starting and i have custom workflow action which create a word document from the item id of the list.

Iam only getting error and no information so i dont know what is the mistake iam doing.

If i start the workflow manuelly its working.

My second workflow looks like this

if "field value" equals "sofortige Implementierung"

then Create Word document from List "Listname" and id "Current item ID" with the name "test".

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could use check in and check out of the list item. Let the first workflow check the item out as the first action. Then the workflow does its thing with the item, and as the last step checks the item back in.

Let the second workflow's first step be to wait until the item is checked in, then do its thing.

This way you can ensure that the second workflow won't do anything until the first workflow is finished.

Edit after comment:

Be flexible. Try troubleshooting. First, log each step to the workflow history, so you can tell where the flaw is in the process.

OK, list items cannot be checked out. Fine.

**Plan B.**

Consider pausing the workflow. How long will the first workflow take? In the second workflow, set the first action to wait for xxx period.

**Plan C:**  (I think this is probably your ticket)

Consider using just **one** workflow with branches. Let it fire when an item is created AND when it is changed. Use conditions to determine what to do. Pseudo code:

```
if field1 is blank (or some other value)
    do this
else if field1 =  "sofortige Implementierung"
    do the steps for that
end if
```

That way you won't have two workflows conflicting over precedence.

Comment: but this is not a document library, its a list. There is no option in List workflow to checkout item. There is item checkout option only for the document library.

Comment: Actually the first workflow sets a Taxonomy field value to "sofortige implementierung" and then set another field "sofortimp" to "sofortige implementierung".  That means the first workflow sets the Field Sofortimp from empty to "sofortige implementierung". So the second workflow run when the field value is changed so i try to log the id it doing perfectly and the error i get is where the second workflow have this custom workflow action which gets the id of the list item and create word document with metadata.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Acutally i mistake was from the Custom workflow action i developed using Visual studio. The problem was i used using(SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.site.ID) there was error saying object reference not set to an instance of an object and corrected that and working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Acutally i mistake was from the Custom workflow action i developed using Visual studio. The problem was i used using(SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.site.ID) there was error saying object reference not set to an instance of an object and corrected that and working fine.